# Installing style50 on windows

Tags: pip, cs50

I was trying to install style50 on windows (having MSYS2) using `pip install style50` , the concluding message doesnt mention of anything failing. But thereafter when I run `style50 --version` for verifying, I get the following error(2):

```
$ pip install style50

Collecting style50
  Using cached style50-2.7.5-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting icdiff
  Downloading icdiff-2.0.5.tar.gz (15 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting jsbeautifier
  Downloading jsbeautifier-1.14.4.tar.gz (74 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 74 kB 474 kB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting termcolor
  Using cached termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz (3.9 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting python-magic
  Downloading python_magic-0.4.27-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting autopep8>=1.4.3
  Using cached autopep8-1.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
Collecting jinja2>=2.10
  Downloading Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 133 kB 1.1 MB/s
Collecting argparse
  Using cached argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting pycodestyle>=2.8.0
  Using cached pycodestyle-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting toml
  Using cached toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (17 kB)
Collecting six>=1.13.0
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting editorconfig>=0.12.2
  Using cached EditorConfig-0.12.3-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for icdiff, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for termcolor, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Building wheels for collected packages: jsbeautifier
  Building wheel for jsbeautifier (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for jsbeautifier: filename=jsbeautifier-1.14.4-py3-none-any.whl size=93566 sha256=d10a21fd9f6ab76149c7440ac34f03eb81bcc7789a847f81704262d4d835ee65
  Stored in directory: c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\80\98\1e\487c168894ca20596545a8bb7addfabc1465ea3a80ef8ba76d
Successfully built jsbeautifier
Installing collected packages: toml, six, pycodestyle, MarkupSafe, editorconfig, termcolor, python-magic, jsbeautifier, jinja2, icdiff, autopep8, argparse, style50
    Running setup.py install for termcolor ... done
    Running setup.py install for icdiff ... done
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-2.1.1 argparse-1.4.0 autopep8-1.6.0 editorconfig-0.12.3 icdiff-2.0.5 jinja2-3.1.2 jsbeautifier-1.14.4 pycodestyle-2.8.0 python-magic-0.4.27 six-1.16.0 style50-2.7.5 termcolor-1.1.0 toml-0.10.2
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

```
$ style50 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\style50.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\style50\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ._api import Style50, StyleCheck, Error
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\style50\_api.py", line 4, in <module>
    import fcntl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation on Github](https://github.com/cs50/style50) (emphasis mine):

> Along with most of CS50's command line tools, style50 supports being run on Windows **but only via the Linux Subsystem in Windows 10**. After launching it, style50 can be installed using the pip command above.

Comment: i have already read that, but surely there must be some way to run it without WSL. oh, sorry, I fordot to mention that I am using MSYS2 which does provide many linux tools on windows. This thought of mine is based on the hypothesis that style50 seems to be just some glue applied on `astyle` (Artistic Style is a source code indenter, formatter, and beautifier) and `git diff`.